# Spark rolling window with multiple occurrence in same date

Tags: pyspark

**Input:**

[image]

**Request:**
Would like to calculate 3 months rolling sum, avg across time.
But, **there are two rows for "2022-07-01"**. Would like to get result for both row.

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `rowsBetween` instead of `rangeBetween`, you can assign a row number to each of the dates in an order and then use that row number in the `sum` and `avg` window.

Below is an example.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('rn', func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy().orderBy('ym'))). \
    withColumn('sum_val_roll3m', 
               func.sum('val').over(wd.partitionBy().orderBy('rn').rowsBetween(-2, 0))
               ). \
    withColumn('mean_val_roll3m', 
               func.avg('val').over(wd.partitionBy().orderBy('rn').rowsBetween(-2, 0))
               ). \
    show()

# +----------+---+---+--------------+-----------------+
# |        ym|val| rn|sum_val_roll3m|  mean_val_roll3m|
# +----------+---+---+--------------+-----------------+
# |2022-03-01|  8|  1|             8|              8.0|
# |2022-04-01|  7|  2|            15|              7.5|
# |2022-05-01|  7|  3|            22|7.333333333333333|
# |2022-06-01| 10|  4|            24|              8.0|
# |2022-07-01|  4|  5|            21|              7.0|
# |2022-07-01|  1|  6|            15|              5.0|
# +----------+---+---+--------------+-----------------+
```